# Inserting Integer Values into MySQL Database using Variables

Tags: java, mysql, sql, integer

```
     Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
     Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test",
     "root", "mysecret");
     System.out.println("Connected to Database");
     Statement stmt1 = conn.createStatement();
     ResultSet rs1=null;
     String sql="insert into id
     values('"+name+"',12,+fs+,+se+,+th+,+ft+,+f+,+si+,+sv+,+ei+)";
     System.out.println("sql:"+sql);
     stmt1.executeUpdate(sql);
```

The Name Variable is taken care of in the definition part not included here, the output is

```
     sql:insert into id values('Golum',12,+fs+,+se+,+th+,+ft+,+f+,+si+,+sv+,+ei+);
```

It also says error in SQL Syntax which refers to the variables fs,se,th,ft,f,si,sv and ei. Basically i am trying to pass integers to MySQL Database using variables. the definition of these variables is as such

```
    int fs = x21;
    int se = y21;
```

x21 and y21 store mouse click co-ordinates x and y respectively. The code below shows that the co-ordinates are passed correctly. The error is in SQL Syntax. I wanna Know what is the correct syntax for passing integers to SQL Database using this technique.

```
    System.out.println(fs);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a SQL error in your insert statement.  I don't know why you have those `+` characters in your statement, but I'm guessing that you are attempting to concatenate the values into the statement.  But in your attempt the `+` characters are part of the string.  Try inserting double-quote characters to end and start the strings to concatenate together to form the insert statement:

```
String sql="insert into id values('"+name+"',12, " +
    fs+","+se+","+th+","+ft+","+f+","+si+","+sv+","+ei+")";
```

Of course anytime you concatenate values that may be from the user into a SQL statement, you are vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).  If these are user values, then use a [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) with bind variables instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell Java to convert your integer variables to strings, change your sql assignment statement to:

```
String sql="insert into id values('"
    + name + "',12," + fs + ", " + se + ","
    + th + "," + ft + "," + f + "," + si + "," + sv + "," + ei + ")";
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
String sql="insert into id values('"+name+"',12,"+fs +","+se+","+th+","+ft+","+f+","+si+","+sv+","+ei+")";
```

your syntax for using vars in the string is wrong. The vars should be out of quotations